# Как работать с моделями в Phalcon?

Tags: php, phalcon

Как работать с моделями в Phalcon? Как их подключать в контроллере?

Тут я уже был - http://docs.phalconphp.com/ru/latest/reference/models.html.
Получается, что нужно просто писать `require` и путь к модели, или как правильно?

В папке моделей файл *MyMod.php*:

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;

class MyMod extends Model
{
    public $value = 12345;
}
```

В папке контроллеров *IndexController.php*:

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $MyMod = new MyMod();
        //как мне здесь вывести value ? 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй вывести его так.

```
echo $MyMod->value;
exit;
```